# AES Decryption in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, encryption

I am attempting to decrypt a string encrypted elsewhere using 128 bit AES password based encryption. While decrypting, it shows the following error in my logcat:

```
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err: javax.crypto.IllegalBlockSizeException: last block incomplete in decryption
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at com.android.org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.symmetric.util.BaseBlockCipher.engineDoFinal(BaseBlockCipher.java:853)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at javax.crypto.Cipher.doFinal(Cipher.java:1502)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at com.example.osho.decrypt2.MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:96)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
04-29 00:26:28.881 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
04-29 00:26:28.882 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
04-29 00:26:28.882 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
04-29 00:26:28.882 2379-2379/? W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My java code is included.

```
Cipher cipher = null;
try {
    cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
} catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(array, "AES");
try {
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE,secretKeySpec);
} catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
byte[] decrypted=new byte[0];
try {
    decrypted=cipher.doFinal(ciphertext.getBytes());
} catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (BadPaddingException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
String plaintext= Base64.encodeToString(decrypted,0);
pt.setText(plaintext);
```

the code for encryption is here....

```
 pt = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pt);
        lat = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lat);
        lon = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.lon);
        ct = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ct);
        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);

       b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               String plaintext = pt.getText().toString();
               String latitude = lat.getText().toString();
               String longitude = lon.getText().toString();

               String key = latitude;
               key = key.concat(longitude);
               byte[] array = new byte[0];
               try {
                   array = key.getBytes("UTF-8");
               } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }

               MessageDigest sha = null;
               try {
                   sha = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-1");
               } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               array = sha.digest(array);
               array = Arrays.copyOf(array, 16); // use only first 128 bit
               Cipher cipher = null;
               try {
                   cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
               } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               SecretKeySpec secretKeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(array, "AES");

               try {
                   cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKeySpec);
               } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               byte[] encrypted = new byte[0];
               try {
                   encrypted = cipher.doFinal((plaintext).getBytes());
               } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
                   e.printStackTrace();
               }
               String ciphertext = Base64.encodeToString(encrypted,0);
               ct.setText(ciphertext);

           }
       });
    }
```

i am trying to encrypt a string in one app and decrypt in another app by using given password...
i am taking input as hello and encrypted string is Odif/0610bdRJKNPEouYvW==

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The ciphertext you provided has not the correct length (it must be a multiple of 16 byte for AES). The issue could be anything. Please show the input, the expected output and the code of how it was encrypted. Having the encryption code makes it much easier to diagnose the problem.

Comment: Can you be sure that the original plaintext was encrypted with ECB mode?  Perhaps an IV is prepended to the ciphertext.

Comment: this is my code for encryption...